# Interpreting STRACE output - pipes and forks

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork, strace

I have the following code written in C, taken from https://beej.us/guide/bgipc/html/multi/pipes.html:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{ 
    int pfds[2];

    pipe(pfds);

    if (!fork()) {
        close(1);       /* close normal stdout */
        dup(pfds[1]);   /* make stdout same as pfds[1] */
        close(pfds[0]); /* we don't need this */
        execlp("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);
    } else {
        close(0);       /* close normal stdin */
        dup(pfds[0]);   /* make stdin same as pfds[0] */
        close(pfds[1]); /* we don't need this */
        execlp("/usr/bin/wc", "wc", "-l", NULL);
    }

return 0;
}
```

When compiling and running this code in the terminal using strace I get the following output:

```
execve("./forks", ["./forks"], [/* 55 vars */]) = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f2b0e498700) = 0
pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
clone(Process 7304 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f2b0e4989d0) = 7304
[pid  7303] execve("/usr/bin/wc", ["wc", "-l"], [/* 55 vars */] <unfinished ...>
[pid  7304] execve("/bin/ls", ["ls"], [/* 55 vars */] <unfinished ...>
[pid  7303] <... execve resumed> )      = 0
[pid  7304] <... execve resumed> )      = 0
[pid  7303] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f558acde700) = 0
[pid  7304] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f4bef4f67c0) = 0
[pid  7304] exit_group(0)               = ?
Process 7304 detached
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
21
exit_group(0)
```

Can anybody explain, line by line, what is going on in the strace output? I've attempted to research how to interpret strace outputs but haven't had any luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
execve("./forks", ["./forks"], [/* 55 vars */]) = 0
```

The shell calls `execve` with your executable and `./forks` as `argv[0]`. The `/* 55 vars */` are the environment variables inherited from the shell.

```
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f2b0e498700) = 0
```

Probably sets up thread local storage for the newly launched process.

```
pipe([3, 4])
```

The `pipe` system call returns a pair of descriptors, `3` and `4`. The numbers are such because no descriptors other than `0` (stdin), `1` (stdout) and `2` (stderr) have been allocated so far to the process.

```
clone(Process 7304 attached child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f2b0e4989d0) = 7304
```

The `clone` system call corresponds to the call to `fork`, spawning a new process. Even though `fork` is commonly referred to as a system call, particularly on Linux it wraps a call to `clone(2)`.

```
[pid  7303] execve("/usr/bin/wc", ["wc", "-l"], [/* 55 vars */] <unfinished ...>
[pid  7304] execve("/bin/ls", ["ls"], [/* 55 vars */] <unfinished ...>
[pid  7303] <... execve resumed> )      = 0
[pid  7304] <... execve resumed> )      = 0
[pid  7303] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f558acde700) = 0
[pid  7304] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f4bef4f67c0) = 0
[pid  7304] exit_group(0)
```

Within the parent and the child, two new executables are started. The child exits with `[pid  7304] exit_group(0)` and the parent immediately receives a `SIGCHLD` signal that a child process has changed its state.

Comment: that's brilliant, thanks a lot. Just a quick one, where exactly are the commands ls and wc are executed?

Comment: `ls` is executed in the child (pid 7304) and `wc` is in the parent (pid 7303).

Comment: so the line `[pid  7303] execve("/usr/bin/wc", ["wc", "-l"], [/* 55 vars */] <unfinished ...>` is where the parent is being executed? @blagovestbuyukliev

Comment: The essential thing to understand about `execve` is that it starts a new process in place of the calling process, but doesn't alter its pid, so the process hierarchy remains unchanged after the call. Pid `7303` exists since your program was launched.

Comment: The "-f" option tells strace to follow child-processes (which works for "most" cases).